# Django's HttpResponseRedirect not visible by Zuul proxy system

Tags: django, redirect, proxy, routes, netflix-zuul

I have **Django** web application and route all requests to this web app via proxy / routing system **Netflix Zuul**.
One of view classes in Django returns **HttpResponseRedirect("/")**, but  this redirect does not visible by Zuul.

Is it possible somehow to setup Zuul proxy or Django web app so all redirections (status codes 301 and 302) will be visible by proxy system? Please explain this behavior.

**Reproduction steps**

I launched Django web app on `localhost:8000`. When in browser I want to point to view class that has redirection:  `"localhost:8000/list"`,
then browser's developer tool displays two requests: first with status code 302 and second with 200, and after redirection link looks like `"localhost:8000/"`.

```
first request:
* Request URL:http://localhost:8000/list
* Request Method:GET
* Status Code:302 FOUND
* Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
and response headers contain:  Location:http://localhost:8000/

second request:
* Request URL:http://localhost:8000/
* Request Method:GET
* Status Code:200 OK
* Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8000
```

After that I applied proxy system and launched it on `localhost:8080` (routing redirects all requests to `localhost:8000`). 
When searching in browser by  `"localhost:8080/list"`, 
browser's developer tool displays only a single request and still stays on the same link (but I need link changed to `"localhost:8080/"` due to redirection)

```
* Request URL:http://localhost:8080/list
* Request Method:GET
* Status Code:200 
* Remote Address:[::1]:8080
```